# Почему PHP не выдаёт предупреждение о том, что элемент doGo массива не инициализирован?

Tags: php, form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="expression">
     <input type="submit" name="doGo" value="Отправить">
    </form>
    <?php
     if ($_REQUEST['doGo']) echo "Вы нажали кнопку.<br>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

В книге приведен пример (см. выше) и говорится, что в данном в случае при первом запуске сценария PHP выдаст предупреждение "элемент массива doGo не инициализирован". И приводятся два обходных варианта:
1) Использовать оператор отключения предупреждений @
2) Проверять существует ли $_REQUEST["doGo"] с помощью isset()

Но у меня итак все хорошо работает. Вопрос: почему?

Comment: Я отредактировал код

Comment: Потому что в PHP у вас отключен вывод ошибок. Или потому, что ошибки у вас пишутся в лог.

Comment: Что вы используете в качестве сервера?

Comment: @Эдуард нет, вывод ошибок включен - я зашел в файл php.ini и в нём для display_errors Default Value: On. И ошибки не пишутся в log для log_errors Default Value: Off

Comment: @AlexeyKapustsin Abyss Web Server

Comment: @JustLearn а в файле .htaccess есть какие-то директивы? Ну и в самОм php файле есть функция error_reporting() ?

Comment: @JustLearn Возможно дело в нём. Стандартный apache выдаёт правильную ошибку `Notice: Undefined index: doGo in /var/www/localhost-dev/index.php on line 15`

Comment: @AlexeyKapustsin возможно

Comment: @AlexeyKapustsin а какую Вы версию php используете? Может быть в ней дело? Я использую 7.3.4

Comment: @JustLearn 7.2 Разницы быть не должно

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL); ??? без этой строки у меня тоже нет ошибок

Comment: @Arendach я не понял о чём Вы